# Is there a relationship between the -e file test and exists function?

Tags: perl

Reading the docs for the [-e file test](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) it says:

-e  File **[exists](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exists.html)**

Is there something, I'm missing about any relationship between `-e` and the `exists` function ?

Comment: There's no connection. The online documentation automatically adds a link when it encounters the name of a built-in function/operator. Notice that there's also a link to `for` in the line `Same for access time.` later in the page, even though there's no talk of loops. These links do not exist in the original POD documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word "exists" there doesn't refer to the `exists()` function; it's just using the word with its ordinary English meaning. The `-e` operator and the `exists` function are unrelated.

`-e filename` tests whether the named file exists in the file system.

The `exists` function tests whether a specified hash or array element exists (even if the corresponding value is `undef`).

Apparently, as ThisSuitIsBlackNot points out in a comment, the online documentation has automatically created links for certain words, including `exists`. Similarly, the description of the `-l` operator:

> `-l`  File is a symbolic *link* (false *if* symlinks aren't supported by the file *system*).

has HTML links for `link`, `if`, and `system`, none of which are directly relevant.

Given that the web pages for the Perl documents have links like this, it might be nice if POD had a syntax to say that a particular word should not be linked -- but I'm not convinced it's worth the effort. The links are easy enough to ignore once you realize what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Not only does the link not exist in the original POD, there is also no such link when you look at it on [metacpan](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#X):

[image: -e docs on metacpan]